# Draw image in activity android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I have a activity where I have two imageViews. In onTouch I recognize which imageView was clicked. Now I have a question. How I can draw new very small image in place where I clicked. I know that onTouch i have getX() and getY() and I save this position when I touch the screen, but I don't know how I can draw image in place where I clicked. My image is in drawable resources. I need to use canvas or is better way. I need draw this picture and after that I need run animation this image.

edit1: How can I set positionX and positionY my image. I have position where I click but I don't know how I can set image in this coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should have a image view with visible attribute of FALSE and after touch (or any event you want)  set three attribute : visible = true; x = getX() and y = getY();

is it enough or explain more?

Comment: I set visibility but I don't know how i can set position this image. I know that getX() and getY() returns place where I click but how I can set this coordinates in images?

Comment: developers.android.com
go to reference tab

Answer (score 0):

I see the following approach.

- Replace the ImageView by a custom view derived from ImageView.
- Override onDraw.
- call super.onDraw to draw the image
- paint your image using onDraw's canvas at the last touch position.
- each time you get a touch, you need to invalidate the custom view